# Find list with specyfic Content type by ID

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint-2010, caml

I need to find out how to get list from site/web if i have only content type ID, there is some about 500 + lists i dont want to "foreach" those like :

```
using (SPSite _SiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb _web = _SiteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                foreach (SPList _list in _web.Lists)
                {
                    foreach (SPContentType _type in _list.ContentTypes)
                    {
                        if (_type.Id == ContentTypeIds.ocTodoCTId)
                        {

                            foreach (SPListItem _item in _list.Items)
                            {

                               //bla bla bla  
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

I found a way how to do this, but its not working on sandbox solution.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage.getusages.aspx

Comment: http://darrinbishop.com/blog/2007/04/spsitedataquery-for-cross-site-and-cross-list-searches

Comment: my effort was using foreach in 3 loops... but thank u Alexei this is what i was looking for !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code that was a solution:

```
  SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">";
                query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1' />";
                query.Query = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='Text'>" +
                    "0x0101006d76968475dd473f92fbdec03bbff85e" +
                    "</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";
```

here we have lists with ur content type